# How to filter and get values ​from a json

Tags: python, json

I have a json like the one below

```
{
  "headers": [
    "product_id",
    "price",
    "is_discontinued"
  ],
  "product_stores": [
    [
      2093085822,
      23.58,
      false
    ],
    [
      2093085837,
      16.1,
      true
    ],
   ...
```

This is a column in a dataframe that contais another columns such as ID, created_at, etc. I would like do have all the product_ids from the column, it could be a string like "2093085822,2093085837" but only if "is_discontinued" is true

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is pretty simple. Just use some list comprehension:

```
json_dict = # Load the json here
what_you_want = [item[0] for item in json_dict["product_stores"] if item[2]]
```

Comment: yes, already fixed it. thanks for alerting me

Comment: did not work it. Error "string indices must be integers"

Answer (score 1):

Similair to Rafael's answer although you can also use named variables in the comprehension so it remains readable:

```
output = [pid for pid, price, discontinued in json_dict["product_stores"] if discontinued]
```

keep in mind all sub-lists need to be of length 3 for this to work

Comment: Complementig, if you don't need `price` you can just replace it with an underline `_`

Comment: yes I originally was going to do that although I kept it in as it's not that long of a name. The underscore still has an assigned variable it's just an obscure name. I usually only use an underscore when the name is long and unneeded

Comment: it did not work. Error: "string indices must be integers"

Comment: First you need to transform the JSON string into a dict object for it to work properly.